# Can I override a grandparent method that is imported into parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I've tried to simplify my situation with some pseudo-code involving Son, Dad, Grandpa:

grandpaClient.js:

```
GrandpaClient = {
  walk: function(){
    // i do stuff that my grandson wants to override
    // i walk slow
    return walkSlow
  }
}

module.exports = GrandpaClient
```

dadClient.js:

```
import GrandpaClient from 'grandpaClient'
export function DadClient(){
  return {
    // i walk just like grandpa
    walk: new Promise((res, rej) => {
            GrandpaClient.walk();
          });
  }
}
```

son.js:

```
import DadClient from 'dadClient'
// i walk just like dad but i want to walk fast
SonClient = createDadClient();
SonClient.walk();
```

can son.js be:

```
import GrandpaClient from 'grandpaClient'
import DadClient from 'dadClient'
GrandpaClient.walk = function() {
  // I don't want to walk like grandpa
  return walkFast
}
// Now I need to tell my dad that grandpa actually walks fast.
// Can I make DadClient use my custom GrandpaClient without modifying DadClient code?
SonClient = DadClient();
SonClient.walk();
```

Suppose I control the source for `SonClient`. Can I accomplish the above without modiyfing the source for `GrandpaClient` and `DadClient`? Or must `DadClient` take in an optional `CustomGrandpaClient` parameter? `DadClient` does not extend `GrandpaClient`, it just consumes the `walk` attribute from the imported `GrandpaClient` object.

I don't want to copy all the logic from `DadClient` by doing `DadClient.walk = function() {...}` from the `SonClient`

Am I asking too much here

Comment: Perhaps you should be using classes and you can then subclass whichever existing class and specify overriden methods to modify the behavior of your subclass.

Comment: yes i think I can't get around editing the other clients.